# How to create a custom SSO Member Login in Umbraco v8 (ADFS - No Azure) using "itfoxtec-identity-saml2" Project?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, umbraco8, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm new with sso login (ADSF - SAML2) with Umbraco v8 and I need some help to know if this is the right package for me.

I'm working on a website using Umbraco CMS v8 and I need to create a custom members login (frontend) using the sso authentication of my company (ADFS - no Azure AD) and my custom login form (C# and .Net Framework 4.7.2+).

I found on NuGet the "itfoxtec-identity-saml2" package that can be used to do it and I saw that there are two packages that could help me: "ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2" and "ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc"

What are the difference and what reccomand to use?

Any other suggestions to create an SSO Members Login in Umbraco v8, is welcome.

Thank you and I look forward to your reply

Adriano

Answer (score 0):

The ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 is the base component implementing the actually SAML 2.0 standard.

The ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc and ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore implements the elements needed to integration with ASP.NET MVC. The ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc component is for .NET Framework and the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore component is for .NET Core and .NET 5.0.

I'm afraid that i do not know anything about Umbraco, sorry I cannot help you there.

Comment: OK, thank you for your support.
I hope someone can help me
Adriano